# Organisation within Menu calculator

Tags: c++, menu, calculator

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

void main_menu();
int get_user_input();
void select_menu_item(int input);
void print_main_menu();
void go_back_to_main_menu();
bool is_integer(std::string num);
void menu_item_1();
void menu_item_2();
void menu_item_3();
void menu_item_4();

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  //int num1, num2, choice, i;
  main_menu();
  return 0;
}

void main_menu() {
  char fav;
 int num1,num2,choice,i;
 cout<<"\n Enter 1st Number: ";
 cin>>num1;
 cout<<"\n Enter 2nd Number: ";
 cin>>num2;
  print_main_menu();
  int input = get_user_input();
  select_menu_item(input);
  //void menu_item_1(); 
}


int get_user_input() {
  int input;
  std::string input_string;
  bool valid_input = false;
  int menu_items = 5;

  do {
    std::cout << "\nSelect item: ";
    std::cin >> input_string;
    valid_input = is_integer(input_string);
    // if input is not an integer, print an error message
    if (valid_input == false) {
      std::cout << "Enter an integer!\n";
    } else {  // if it is an int, check whether in range
      input = std::stoi(input_string);  // convert to int
      if (input >= 1 && input <= menu_items) {
        valid_input = true;
      } else {
        std::cout << "Invalid menu item!\n";
        valid_input = false;
      }
    }
  } while (valid_input == false);

  return input;
}

void select_menu_item(int input) {
  switch (input) {
    case 1:
      menu_item_1();
       break;
    case 2:
      menu_item_2();
      break;
    case 3:
      menu_item_3();
      break;
    case 4:
      menu_item_4();
      break;
    default:
      exit(1);
      break;
  }
}

void print_main_menu() {
  
  std::cout << "\n----------- Main menu -----------\n";
  std::cout << "|\t\t\t\t\t\t|\n";
  std::cout << "|\t1. Menu item 1\t\t|\n";
  std::cout << "|\t2. Menu item 2\t\t|\n";
  std::cout << "|\t3. Menu item 3\t\t|\n";
  std::cout << "|\t4. Menu item 4\t\t|\n";
  std::cout << "|\t5. Exit\t\t\t\t|\n";
  std::cout << "|\t\t\t\t\t\t|\n";
  std::cout << "---------------------------------\n";
}

void go_back_to_main() {
  std::string input;
  do {
    std::cout << "\nEnter 'b' or 'B' to go back to main menu: ";
    std::cin >> input;
  } while (input != "b" && input != "B");
  main_menu();
}

// https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/162569/checking-if-each-char-in-a-string-is-a-decimal-digit
bool is_integer(std::string num) {
  return std::regex_match(num, std::regex("[+-]?[0-9]+"));
}

void menu_item_1() {
  
  int num1, num2, choice, i;
  std::cout << "\n>> Menu 1\n";
  std::cout << "\n Sum of "<< num1 <<" and "<< num2;
            cout << " = "<<num1+num2;
  //std::cin>> Menu_item 1;         
  // you can call a function from here that handles menu 1
  go_back_to_main();
}
void menu_item_2() {
  std::cout << "\n>> Menu 2\n";
  std::cout << "\nSome code here does something useful\n";
  // you can call a function from here that handles menu 2
  go_back_to_main();
}
void menu_item_3() {
  std::cout << "\n>> Menu 3\n";
  std::cout << "\nSome code here does something useful\n";
  // you can call a function from here that handles menu 3
  go_back_to_main();
}
void menu_item_4() {
  std::cout << "\n>> Menu 4\n";
  std::cout << "\nSome code here does something useful\n";
  // you can call a function from here that handles menu 4
  go_back_to_main();
}
```

output:

```
Enter 1st Number: 56

 Enter 2nd Number: 87

----------- Main menu -----------
|                       |
|   1. Menu item 1      |
|   2. Menu item 2      |
|   3. Menu item 3      |
|   4. Menu item 4      |
|   5. Exit             |
|                       |
---------------------------------

Select item: 1

>> Menu 1

 Sum of 0 and 6596224 = 6596224
Enter 'b' or 'B' to go back to main menu:
```

I feel I am close to getting the first menu function working however I can't work out why the output for Menu 1 keeps returning "Sum of 0 and 6596224 = 6596224". I am not sure which part of the code needs rearranging.

I am aware I have only completed the addition but once I have figured out what is going wrong here I'm sure I will be able to complete the rest of it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`num1` in `main` and `num1` in `menu_item_1()` are two completely unrelated variables. Same for `num2`. Both are not initialized in `menu_item_1`.

If you already read the values before, you can pass them to the function:

```
void menu_item_1(int num1, int num2) {
  std::cout << "\n>> Menu 1\n";
  std::cout << "\n Sum of " << num1 << " and " << num2;
  std::cout << " = " << num1+num2;
}
```

I do not understand the purpose of `go_back_to_main`, because it keeps the user in an infinite loop and the only choice they have is to confirm by typing either `'b'` or `'B'`, hence I removed it.

Comment: Okay thank you for the reply. When you are referring to ` menu_item_1 ` , is this within case 1? After adjusting the code the output is now   ` /tmp/main-f98a55.o: In function select_menu_item(int)': main.cpp:(.text+0x3b2): undefined reference to menu_item_1()' clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) exit status 1 `

Comment: @JJB you have to learn how to pass parameters to functions, should be explained in any introductory book. You not only have to change the definition of the function, but also your declaration and when calling you have to pass parameters